# createBitmap method of Bitmap class returns an error

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am writing the code of scaling the bitmap and create new Bitmap usint Bitmap.createBitmap() method that returns always an error which can't be recognized by me. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**ErrorStack:**

```
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TestFace.FaceDetect/com.TestFace.FaceDetect.ProcessImage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at com.TestFace.FaceDetect.ProcessImage.scaleImage(ProcessImage.java:247)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at com.TestFace.FaceDetect.ProcessImage.onCreate(ProcessImage.java:67)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-22 16:27:14.679: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    ... 11 more
```

**Code:**

```
 private Bitmap scaleImage(Bitmap paramBitmap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int i = paramBitmap.getWidth();
         System.out.println("Width========="+i);
            int j = paramBitmap.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Height========="+j);
            float f2 = j / i * 300;
            float f1 = 300 / i;
            f2 /= j;
            Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
            localMatrix.postScale(f1, f2);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(paramBitmap, 0, 0, i, j, localMatrix, false);
    }
```

Comment: The exception clearly states that width and height must be > 0, you have them equal to 0.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`? It does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: is the  System.out.println("Width========="+i); prints the correct width or it prints 0?

Comment: @SteveL yes this prints the correct output.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);
```